# Fetching records in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have 3 tables table1, table2 and employee table.
In table1 I have columns **status_code** (which can be Assigned or Unassigned) and **table1Id**

In table2 I have Columns **table1Id** as foreign key and **employee_id** as other column and

In table3 **employee** I have columns **employee_first_name**, **employee_last_name** and **employee_id** and **department_id**

Now, i am trying to get all those records which are if it is assigned status then want there employee first and last name and if it is unassigned then empty value in emplyee_first_name and last_name columns. 
If status is unassigned then there will be no first name and last name, only employee_id and department id will be there in employee table

I am using :

```
select
   t1.table1Id, Emp.FIRST_NAME,Emp.LAST_NAME
from
   table1 t1, table2 t2 , employee emp 
where
   t1.status in (2733,2734) 
and
   t2.tableId2 = t1.tableId1 and t2.employee_id = emp.employee_id;
```

This query is giving me only those records for which status is assigned and when i am removing t2.employee_id = emp.employee_id check then giving those records for which status is assigned as well as those for which status is unassigned but for this it is giving all other first_name and last_name corresponding to unassigned status.

Comment: You are looking for a left join

Answer (score 0):

```
 select
 t1.table1Id, Emp.first_name, Emp.last_name
 from
 table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on (t1.tableId1 = t2.tableId2)
 left join employee Emp on (t2.employee_id = Emp.employee_id)
 where
 t1.status in (2733,2734)
```